# Differences between REST communication and message oriented communication

Tags: system, distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-system, distributed-transactions

I'm a bit confused with Differences between REST communication and message oriented communication. I can not find their differences either on the internet or in a book, do you have something to suggest to me